# Pick a section of an image in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an image with multiple portraits inside, how can I pick each one of them without cutting the image in photoshop or something like that. The image would be 8 images in row by 3 columns can I do this programatically? Links would help to learn about this topic, not looking for free code, I genuinly don't know how to google for this.
I know in Unity they use images like that for animations and I guess somehow loop through them. In my case I only need to pick one randomly.

I added unity tag because game developers might be more familiar with this.
If my title isn't great please free to edit it.

[This is the image](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/round-avatars-set-with-faces-people-comic-portraits-happy-social-media-users_22676039.htm#query=faces%20cartoon&position=21&from_view=search)

thank you

Comment: The term is ["tiles", "tilemaps", "tile sheets", "sprite", or "sprite maps"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps). The actual implementation (and therefor the answer to this post) depends on the implementation. What format of image is this?

Comment: `Vector in EPS format` this is written under the image

Comment: You'll probably need to rasterize a vector image before you can split it up, or you'll need to manually remove the instructions for the other elements to exclude.

Comment: Actually, the correct term is "texture atlas" when it does not apply specifically to games.

Will the atlas from which you want to pick a sub-image, be a fixed set of images, or will it change?

Comment: I have a chat app in netcore, signalr and angular and I am trying to set random avatars and usernames to users that aren't authenticated. Thought would be a great idea to explore this topic a little bit with this opportunity rather than having a list of links with images and pick an random index. Basically the image in the link will stay the same and not change(if I understood the question), the app is just for demonstration purposes is gonna be deployed only for me to show it for jobs and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can import texture as multiple sprites. Select it in the project hierarchy and then select `Multiple`.

.[image]

After that, you can click `Sprite Editor` to split the texture.

[image]

[image]

In my case, it sliced the picture like this:

[image]